# Утечка памяти pygame

Tags: python-3.x

Через диспетчер задач обнаружил утечку памяти во время выполнения данного кода, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка

```py
import pygame
class Base(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.x = 10
  def update(self):
    self.x -= 1
group = pygame.sprite.Group()
pygame.init()
while True:
  new_base = Base()
  group.add(new_base)
  group.update()
  for base in group.copy():
    if base.x < 0:
      group.remove(base)
```